# How to convert an sql data retrieval into mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Imagine there are two collections in MongoDB User and History. Here I have written the SQL query of a data retrieval if those are in a relational DB. I want to prepare a similar query for this in MongoDB.

(**History** table contains many records for a particular **User**)

```
SELECT U.id FROM User U
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM History H
            WHERE H.userId = U.id AND H.usage > 25 AND H.balance < 100) 
AND U.category = 'VIP' AND U.area = 'XXX';
```

Comment: can you describe that in words? Are you bringing data from history collection based on a relationship between user data and history data? Sounds like a `$lookup`

Comment: I want to get the Users who are satisfying the User related fields, the same time they should be in the History collection with those given usages and balance values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding of question i have written query using `$lookup`. Hope this is what you are looking for. Also adding link to MongoPlaygroud so that you can run the query.

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "history",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "userId",
      "as": "history"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "category": "VIP",
      "area": "XXX",
      "history.usage": {
        "$gt": 25
      },
      "history.balance": {
        "$lt": 100
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "id": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_p-J-Mq1x-p)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to retrieve users in a collection based on a condition in a different collection.

But the following query filters users, and brings data to those you asked for. If this is not found, an empty array is retrieved, so we filter those out.

I'll show you a way with `$graphLookup`

```
//from users 
var pipeline = [
{ $match:{category:"VIP", area:"XXX"} }, //get a subset of users
{ $graphLookup:{  //include docs from History as "myNewData"
  from:"History",
  as:"myNewData", 
  startWith:"$id", //match _id with 
  connectToField:"userId", //userId in History
  connectFromField:"id", //this is irrelevant
  maxDepth:0, //because is used for depth > 0
  restrictSearchWithMatch:{usage:{$gt:25}, balance:{$lt:100}} //condition }
}, 
{$match:{"myNewData":{$elemMatch:{$exists:true}}}
}]

db.Users.aggregate(pipeline)
```

- Collections have to be in the same database.
- No data is permanently moved unless you use `$out` or other stage.
- This should perform better than $lookup (only a subset of docs is brought over)
- [Test here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t7FNoNdGjwH) (I just tweaked the example provided by @zac786)